# trigger browser to send NTLM credentials to web service

Tags: c#, web-services, ntlm

I have `IHttpHandler` type web service written in C# running on IIS 7.5.

I am calling this service from browser using 
    `<script scr = "http://service/method"/>` tag and pushing the results into JS code with JSONP.

Is it possible to make the browser add extra NTLM authorization headers to the request? I need the service to use the same privileges as the caller has.

Can I build something similar to SharePoint automatic sign-on? EG. that web service will initally respond with 401 and WWW-Authenticate header, which will trigger my browser to resend the request that now contains Authorization header (and after that the other NTLM steps will continue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using ASP.NET's [Windows Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx).